# Howto add a string to the 'type <filename>' DOS command before merging into file?

Tags: sql, dos, concatenation, string-concatenation, batch-file

Question: I've several text files containing sql create table/column/view/storedProcedure textfiles. Now I want to merge the textfiles into one textfile.

I go into the directory, and type:

```
type *.sql >> allcommands.sql
```

Now to problem is I should add the text ' GO ' after every file's content.

I can append Go by doing

```
type *.sql >> allcommands.sql & echo  GO  >> allcommands.sql
```

But this only inserts go once.
How can I accomplish this with DOS commands ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
for %%f in (*.sql) do type %%f >>allcommands.sql & echo GO >> allcommands.sql
```

The `%%` is for use in a batch file. If you're not running it from a batch file you only need single % signs.

Comment: +1.  Nice to be proven wrong with a good answer like that, and learn something new.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
for %%f in (*.sql) do (
type %%f >>allcommands.sql
echo. >> allcommands.sql
echo GO >> allcommands.sql
echo. >> allcommands.sql )
```

it adds newline then go for each SQL file. it works for me try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_%28command%29) to concatenate the first file with a file with "GO" text, then concatenate again with the second file.

Comment: That would work, but he would have to manually specify the order of the files to copy.. This would not be able to be done with a "*.sql".  And that would be more work than just typing the word "GO" in manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
CLS
::concat.bat outfile.sql
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

If EXIST GOTMP.TMP DEL /Q GOTMP.TMP
Echo GO>GOTMP.TMP
ECHO.>>GOTMP.TMP

If EXIST "%~1" DEL /Q "%~1"
Echo.>"%~1"

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir  /a-d /on /b "*.sql"') do call :perfaction "%%A%" "%~1"
ECHO Done Generating Output "%~1"
ECHO.
pause
Goto :EOF

:perfaction
ECHO "%~1"
copy "%~2"+"%~1"+GOTMP.TMP "%~2"
GOTO :EOF
```